# Redis connection pooling with JedisPool becoming too verbose

Tags: java, redis, connection-pooling, jedis

Here is my **JedisFactory**

```
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig;

class JedisFactory {
    private static JedisPool jedisPool;
    private static JedisFactory instance;

    public JedisFactory() {
        jedisPool = new JedisPool(getPoolConfig(), "localhost");
    }

    private JedisPoolConfig getPoolConfig() {
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        //poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        //poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(2);
// Tests whether connections are dead during idle periods
        //poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(2);
        //poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(120000);
        return poolConfig;
    }

    public JedisPool getJedisPool() {
        System.out.println("get pool");
        return jedisPool;
    }

    public static JedisFactory getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new JedisFactory();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And here is the usage:

```
public static void del(String key) {
        Jedis jedis = JedisFactory.getInstance().getJedisPool().getResource();
        try {
            jedis.del(key);
        } finally {
            JedisFactory.getInstance().getJedisPool().returnResource(jedis);
        }
    }


    public static String ping() {
        Jedis jedis = JedisFactory.getInstance().getJedisPool().getResource();
        try {
            return jedis.ping();
        } finally {
            JedisFactory.getInstance().getJedisPool().returnResource(jedis);
        }
    }
    public static void clear() {
        Jedis jedis = JedisFactory.getInstance().getJedisPool().getResource();
        try {
            jedis.flushAll();
        } finally {
            JedisFactory.getInstance().getJedisPool().returnResource(jedis);
        }
    }
```

So, for every operation, I have to type in lots of boilerplate code. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your JedisFactory.getInstance() factory method is not thread-safe. You can have more than one JedisFactory instance on the fly.
2. If you use JDK 7 and recent Jedis version, you can just use try-with-resource.

   try (Jedis jedis = JedisFactory.getInstance().getJedisPool().getResource()) {
       jedis.flushAll();
   }

Above code will work.

3. Since JedisPool is thread-safe, you can just initialize JedisPool and pass to anywhere. If you want to keep using JedisFactory, you can minimize your code via adding util method like JedisFactory.getResource() and let getResource() does all the work for caller. Since you create JedisFactory there's no need to expose internal JedisPool field to the public.